# threads works seperatly from each other

Tags: python, multithreading

i try to create multi threading progarm, right now the log to the console always by the order of the threads (https://ibb.co/L0sYKXz)
in my code, every thread should insert 3 items to a matrix (this is why there is 3 logs for each thread) and right now each thread insert its items to the matrix and than the next thread inserting
isnt its should by mixed between the threads? so the a thread insert item to the matrix, and than other thread does the same?
how can i fix it?
thank.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
for i in range(10):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=thread_task,args=(lock,),name=str(i+1)))

for i in range(10):
    threads[i].start()

for i in range(10):
    threads[i].join()



def thread_task(lock):
    lock.acquire()
    dosomething
    print('Thread Number: '+format(threading.current_thread().name))
    lock.release()
```

Comment: You explicitly make your program serial with the lock. Each thread does its work, then the next one acquires the lock, and so on.

Comment: If you protect the whole thread by a lock it does not make sense to run multiple instances of it.

Comment: The order in which the threads are executed cannot be determined. Yours just happen to be executing in sequence but that's by no means guaranteed to happen. There's no need to pass a reference to the lock as it's available in the global address space. I assume you're using a lock because you're modifying something that's not thread safe. Is that so? If you need to use a lock, please consider using *with lock* (Context Manager)